# How do I make conditional Joins within powerBI where there are multiple conditions

Tags: sql, join, powerbi, dax, m

I'm having trouble trying to make a conditional join within Power BI. I have Table A is the fact table. Table B is the table I'm trying to join.

Table A consists of transactions. Each transaction has a record with the method of the process (A,B,C).

The second table is a table of available options for the process method. These two tables come from different sources.

I'm looking for a way to join these tables where I can find the least expensive process method, AND so that a bunch of conditions are satisfied. For example, the In the transaction table, With Export Country CN and Import County US, two methods were used. I would like to join the MOST correct process method so I can determine how much money could have been saved if the correct method was used.

My assumption is that I have to create a new table using DAX and ADDcolumns and Summarize, but I would also need to using some nested conditioning and not sure where that comes into play.

Example, Join the minimum Process Method Cost from Table B where expiry < TableA.process date

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a view over Table B that has the minimum cost records and join to that?